# Converting Binary Data to String [In Persian]

Tags: c#, string, binary, persian

I am working on a system that needs to read a binary file containing certain Persian names/stock instruments. I need to convert the binary data into string to be used in further processes. I have googled it and haven't really found a solution to my problem. Anyone here who has worked in such a scenario or knows how to tackle such a problem?

Here is the code that I am using to convert the bytes to string (simple as it maybe):

```
byte[] data = binaryReader.ReadBytes(amountOfData);
string symbolRead = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

FYI, I have tried to change my system locale to Persian and that hasn't helped either. Although it does allow me to view already written text in Persian.

Hoping to find a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `ASCII` for encoding. First try using `Default` after setting your locale; then try asking directly someone what encoding is most used for Persia, and use this one.

Comment: If you work with `CultureInfo`, I've just found `CultureInfo.TextInfo.ANSICodePage` which should be used in conjunction with the Persian culture and `Encoding.GetEncoding(Int32)` to get the right encoding regardless of the current locale.

Answer (score 0):

Determine what coding is used in your file and use the corresponding encoding instead of `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(...)`. Possible values could be `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(...)` or `Encoding.Default.GetString(...)` to use your system encoding. [See documentation of the Encoding class for other possibilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx).