# Binary File as string

Tags: c#, binary

I want to read binary files as plain text.

Is it possible to do so ?

Want to read whole file as plain text I have managed to view the data with hex viewer freefileviewer, but thing is I want to do it via coding in c#. The binary file I am trying to read is some devices input which operates directly from the binary file i need to modify certain contents of the binary file and resend it for processing.

Comment: Why can't you just read the binary file as a binary file? (I.e. as a `byte[]`?) From what you describe it doesn't really contain text.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651746/converting-binary-data-to-string-in-persian?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binary To Corresponding ASCII String Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006425/binary-to-corresponding-ascii-string-conversion)

Comment: To the auto-downvoter of the "hexviever" answers: read carefully: `have managed to view the data with hex viewer freefileviewer, but thing is I want to do it via coding in c#`. That's why these answers are posted. If you downvote, at least add some comment why so.

Comment: @millimoose I am reading binary file as binary but I have to modify its contents as well for processing. I am unable to parse the raw data into readable format so that I can modify the certain parameter values if there is a way around I am all ears.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to convert `binary` to plain text:

```
var binData = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\path\\to\\file.bin");
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var b in binData)
    sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
var strData = sb.ToString();
```

You can edit it after and convert back to bytes. You can output text data to a user and convert back like this:

```
var bytes = new List<byte>();
for (int i = 0; i < strData.Length; i+=2)
{
    bytes.Add(Byte.Parse(strData[i].ToString() + strData[i+1].ToString(),
       NumberStyles.HexNumber));
}
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\path\\to\\file.bin", bytes.ToArray());
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this would at all help process raw device input data.

Comment: The question is about binary file!

Comment: +1: I don't know why have this been downvoted. Downvoters, please comment. The code in this answer seems to encode/decode the data "as the HexViever" just as the author asked for (unless there are bugs I didnt notice). Of course keeping data as hexstring is a nonsense, but **it this does not** make this answer invalid.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Thanks for support! Double downvotes without any explanation!

Comment: Most probably, because the first line says "as plain text" and hex-view is certainly not it. However, authors says "have managed to view the data with hex viewer freefileviewer, but thing is I want to do it via coding in c#", which the downvoter probably missed/misread. Just guessing though. Anyways, this question should be closed ;)

Answer (score -2):

You should read with `FileStream` and then convert with `ToBase64String`.
See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980182/binary-file-to-string)

```
string myString;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("\\YourPath", FileMode.Open))
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
{
    byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
    myString = Convert.ToBase64String(bin);
}
```

Comment: -1: yeah, try editing base64'ed data..